# Rename Any Kind of File In Specific Part Using Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

My Question is I have a folder with a name "xyz" somewhere, for example it is on desktop and there are 2 excel files namely a,b in that xyz folder.  I work in excel workbook "a" which consist of two names i,j in some cell values for example i is in cellA1, j is in A2.

Now I want to rename excel files a,b with i,j with of without opening or closing files after renaming.  It is possible. If possible please post me the code.  I have no code....please provide from scratch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming files with VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374013/renaming-files-with-vba)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the answer by a simple search of previous questions. I easily found this which should get you on the right path:
[Renaming files with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374013/renaming-files-with-vba)